# Connecting relays to a Raspberry Pi via radio

Tags: wireless, java, relay, nrf24l01

For example, I have a relay that turns lights on/off in my room, and a Raspberry Pi in another room. Is there any way to send commands to relay wirelessly?

I googled and found `NRF24L01` transmitters and [this Java library](https://github.com/anvo/rf24-bcm-java), but I don't understand many things about connecting transmitter to the relay. I need your help a lot, thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use readymade remote-controlled sockets. They *should* be tested AND work already. [image]

The hard part is replacing the supplied remote with a cheap 433 Mhz transciever , which might need reverse-engineering , see here :

http://www.instructables.com/id/Mercury-RF-Remote-Socket-Control-From-Raspberry-Pi/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But is there a way to  control relays as these http://m.aliexpress.com/item/32325545871.html? Or if I had servos - can I rotate them by the radio?

Comment: Such Relays boards do not have RF capability by definition. You would have do design an add-on board for RX/decoding/error correction and it will be uncertified - if you have confidence in your EE skills , certainly an option.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an article about doing what flakeshake suggests in the February 2016 edition of the MagPi.

Alternatively (depending on where you live) you could buy the Energenie [sockets and Pi controller board](https://energenie4u.co.uk/index.php/catalogue/product/ENER002-2PI).

These are for UK sockets but they also do a [European socket version](https://energenie4u.co.uk/catalogue/product/ENER002-2PI-EUR).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [WebIOPi](http://www.trouch.webiopi.com) and send **HTTP** or **CoAP** to send control signals to your relay switches through *WIFI or Ethernet*

If your relays are connected to GPIO you could access the Raspberry Pi's Webpage provided on the WebIOPi to control or trigger things. I use is for my work.

If you are using the **WebIOPI** with **Raspberry Pi 2 Model B** use this patch to make the application work -> [PatchforRPi2](https://github.com/doublebind/raspi) and follow the **README**